# How to pull Azure AD Application Logo

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.GraphHelper v1.0.0.0 library to pull Azure Apps into my App & was able to pull but it is missing App Logo. How to pull AD App Logo ?

Comment: Can you give a little more information? what is the AD app logo?

Comment: App registered in Azure ActiveDirectory..